# Keep focus on Java game for Key Listener

Tags: java, swing, focus, jframe

I'm working on Java game development, and an issue I'm running into is implementing key strokes. The code I have properly implements the KeyListeners, but as soon as I click on the game window or outside of it, the KeyListener stops working.

I'm sure this is a focus issue as I can minimize the window and bring it back up and the KeyListener will work again.

My setup is a JFrame that contains a Canvas object for drawing. I have a regular KeyListener that I add to the JFrame.

So, I'm guessing, when I click on the game, the Canvas gains focus? It shouldn't though, as I set isFocasable() to false.

Here is some of the code I'm using, just so there isn't any confusion:

Here, I create the screen and canvas

```
public final void initScreen(DisplayMode dm, boolean fs, boolean vs)
{
    screen = new EScreen (dm, fs, vs); 
    canvas = new EGameCanvas (screen);
    canvas.setFocusable (false);
    screen.add(canvas);

    keyMapManager = KeyMapManager.getInstance (this);

    if (fs) {
        screen.setFullScreen ();
    }
    else {
        screen.setWindowed ();
    }
}
```

This is where I add the KeyListener (Note that a KeyMap implements KeyListener and nothing more)

```
public boolean setActiveKeyMap(String newKeyMap)
{
    if (keyMaps.containsKey(newKeyMap)) {
        screen.removeKeyListener (activeKeyMap);
        activeKeyMap = keyMaps.get (newKeyMap);
        screen.addKeyListener (keyMaps.get (newKeyMap));

        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

And here is my keyPressed event that simply changed a variable

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent ev) {
    if (ev.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE)
        game.setIsRunning (false);
}
```

Please note, all this code works just fine. That is, until I click on the game window. I don't have any MouseListeners implemented anywhere. Also, I do implement this code:

```
screen.setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled (false);
```

And finally, as you can see, my game handles both full screen mode and windowed mode. This problem occurs in both.

Comment: The proper solution is to use KeyBindings which avoid those focus problems. See the [keybindings tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: I understand that KeyBindings is the suggested solution. But, out of curiousity, isn't there a way to handle focusing issues with KeyListeners?

Comment: @Troncoso *isn't there a way to handle focusing issues with KeyListeners* yes call `requestFocusInWindow();` whenever you see the focus changes, i.e overriding `JFrame#windowDeiconfied(..)` and requesting focus on your `JPanel`. But Keybindings is the solution. +1 Robin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the same configuration for a game of mine: 
add the keyListener to the canvas instead of the JFrame

you can also add it to both the JFrame and the canvas (the same keyListener) if you still want the JFrame to send the events

```
canvas.addKeyListener(this);
```

*this: assuming the object you are implements the KeyListener interface

Comment: This is what I was forgetting to do. Thank you very much.